# Recursively find a deeply nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested-lists

Lets say if we have a deeply nested comment of comments.

```
const comments = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "Comment 1",
    comments: [
      {
        id: 11,
        text: "Comment 1a",
        comments: [
          {
            id: 111,
            text: "Comment 11a",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 112,
            text: "Comment 11b",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 113,
            text: "Comment 11c",
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        text: "Comment 12",
        comments: [
          {
            id: 121,
            text: "Comment 12a",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 122,
            text: "Comment 12b",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 123,
            text: "Comment 12c",
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 13,
        text: "Comment 1c",
        comments: [
          {
            id: 124,
            text: "Comment 13a",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 125,
            text: "Comment 13b",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 126,
            text: "Comment 13c",
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: "Comment 2",
    comments: [
      {
        id: 21,
        text: "Comment 2a",
        comments: [
          {
            id: 127,
            text: "Comment 21a",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 128,
            text: "Comment 21b",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 129,
            text: "Comment 21c",
            comments: [
              {
                id: 130,
                text: "Comment 21cc",
                comments: [
                  {
                    id: 131,
                    text: "Comment 21ccc",
                    comments: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        text: "Comment 2b",
        comments: [
          {
            id: 135,
            text: "Comment 21a",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 132,
            text: "Comment 21b",
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 133,
            text: "Comment 21c",
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 23,
        text: "Comment 2c",
        comments: [],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: "Comment 3",
    comments: [
      {
        id: 31,
        text: "Comment 3a",
        comments: [],
      },
      {
        id: 32,
        text: "Comment 3b",
        comments: [],
      },
      {
        id: 33,
        text: "Comment 3c",
        comments: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

How would we find a deeply nested comment such as comment with the id of 131?
I tried the following and it works.

```
function recursiveFind(comments, commentId) {
  const result = [];
  function loop(comments, commentId, result) {
    for (const comment of comments) {
      if (comment.id === commentId) {
        result.push(comment);
      }
      if (result.length <= 0 && comment.comments) {
        loop(comment.comments, commentId, result);
      }
    }
  }
  loop(comments, commentId, result);
  return result.length > 0 ? result[0] : false;
}
const found = recursiveFind(comments, 131);
console.log(found);//returns object
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this ? I know another option would be flattening the array and then returning the object?

However, is there a better way to do this ?

Thank you.

Edit: Yes ID is unique, I have corrected the id.

Comment: Would make more sense to return an Array of comments given that user (?) ID, Not an object. Or, if it's not a user ID you poorly formatted your question. (Notice i.e: the duplicate `130` ID)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry my bad, id is suppose to be unique

Answer (score 3):

We already have a free tree walker in JS - `JSON.stringify`:

```
function find(data, fn) {
    let found = []

    JSON.stringify(data, (key, val) => {
        if (fn(val))
            found.push(val)
        return val
    })

    return found
}
```

and then simply:

```
results = find(comments, x => x.id === 131)
```

Comment: Really elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.reduce()` and a recursion:

```js
const comments = [ { id: 1, text: "Comment 1", comments: [ { id: 11, text: "Comment 1a", comments: [ { id: 111, text: "Comment 11a", comments: [], }, { id: 112, text: "Comment 11b", comments: [], }, { id: 113, text: "Comment 11c", comments: [], }, ], }, { id: 12, text: "Comment 12", comments: [ { id: 121, text: "Comment 12a", comments: [], }, { id: 122, text: "Comment 12b", comments: [], }, { id: 123, text: "Comment 12c", comments: [], }, ], }, { id: 13, text: "Comment 1c", comments: [ { id: 124, text: "Comment 13a", comments: [], }, { id: 125, text: "Comment 13b", comments: [], }, { id: 126, text: "Comment 13c", comments: [], }, ], }, ], }, { id: 2, text: "Comment 2", comments: [ { id: 21, text: "Comment 2a", comments: [ { id: 127, text: "Comment 21a", comments: [], }, { id: 128, text: "Comment 21b", comments: [], }, { id: 129, text: "Comment 21c", comments: [ { id: 130, text: "Comment 21cc", comments: [ { id: 131, text: "Comment 21ccc", comments: [], }, ], }, ], }, ], }, { id: 22, text: "Comment 2b", comments: [ { id: 130, text: "Comment 21a", comments: [], }, { id: 132, text: "Comment 21b", comments: [], }, { id: 133, text: "Comment 21c", comments: [], }, ], }, { id: 23, text: "Comment 2c", comments: [], }, ], }, { id: 3, text: "Comment 3", comments: [ { id: 31, text: "Comment 3a", comments: [], }, { id: 32, text: "Comment 3b", comments: [], }, { id: 33, text: "Comment 3c", comments: [], }, ], }, ];

function recursiveFind(comments, commentId) {
  const result = comments.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if(obj.id === commentId) {
      acc = obj;
    } else if(obj.comments.length) {
      const found = recursiveFind(obj.comments, commentId);
      if(found) acc = found;
    }
    return acc;
  }, null);
  return result;
}

console.log('search id 131:', recursiveFind(comments, 131));
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": 131,
  "text": "Comment 21ccc",
  "comments": []
}
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

**UPDATE 1** to address feedback that IDs are not unique. I also remove nested comments; if thatit desired, remove the `.map(obj => ({ id: obj.id, text: obj.text }))`

**UPDATE 2** reverted update 1 since IDs are actually unique.

Comment: This will return only a single comment, whereas it would make more sense to return an array of comments by user ID. (Notice that ID refer to a user, since there are duplicate IDs. i.e: `130`) - Or perhaps it's a miss from OP's side.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: See updated answer to address the feedback that IDs are not unique.

Comment: Thank you. yes ids are suppose to be unique, it was my fault that I accidentally added duplicated ids.

Comment: Ok, I reverted UPDATE 1